# How do I select MySQL records based on results from a related table?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in this scenario: members and team_members.  The members table is pretty self explanatory.  The team members table stores the member's team information if they are a member of the team.  If there is no row in the team members table that has a member_id of a user, then they are not in a team.  What I want to do is get all the users that are not members of a team.  Should I use left join, inner join, outer join, or just join?  What would this query look like?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `member_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `display_name` text NOT NULL,
  `email_address` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `activation_code` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_members` (
  `team_member_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` text NOT NULL,
  `date_left` text NOT NULL,
  `total_xp` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`team_member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, the below query is fine

```
SELECT members.member_id 
FROM   members 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN team_members 
                    ON team_members.member_id = members.member_id 
WHERE  team_members.member_id IS NULL
```

This will do, but on reading your question again, you seem to have a date_left column and if you want only those members who have not yet left a team then

```
SELECT members.member_id 
FROM   members 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   team_members 
                        WHERE  team_members.date_left != '') CURRENT_TEAMS 
                    ON CURRENT_TEAMS.member_id = members.member_id 
WHERE  CURRENT_TEAMS.member_id IS NULL
```

SQLFiddle example 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46b25/6/0

Comment: This is assuming you store a '' in the date left initially

Comment: The second query you provided is exactly what I need.  However, team_members.date_left != '') should actually not have a ! since that gets members that have left a team.  But thank you!

Comment: @ShoeLace1291, thanks for the comment, glad that I could help, I have tested the query once again in the fiddle and even though it looks a little confusing, it brought me the right results, thanks for accepting

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to write this query.

To me this is the easiest to read and understand:

```
select * from members where member_id not in (select member_id from team_members).
```

This is a really simple way to write it. If you decide you want everything you can quickly comment out the where clause:

```
select m.* from members m left outer join team_members tm on m.member_id = tm.member_id
where tm.member_id is null
```

This way doesn't seem very popular from the SQL I read but I think it's straightforward:

```
select m.* from members m where not exists
    (select member_id from team_members tm where tm.member_id = m.member_id)
```

Comment: Its preferable to avoid IN, my personal favourite would be the second